# Метод FormatDate класса Utilities Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

В моём скрипте я получаю значение ячейки (содержимое - дата в кратком формате dd.mm.yyyy, ячейка в формате "Дата") и сравниваю его с текущей датой. Если значения совпадают (запись сделана сегодня) - выполняются дальнейшие действия.

Для корректного сравнения я преобразовывал значения ячейки в формат даты с помощью метода Utilities.FormatDate:

```
  var lastDate = sheet.getRange(i-1,4).getValue();//Получение даты последней записи
  var lastDate = Utilities.formatDate(lastDate, '+0300', 'dd.MM.yyyy');//Получение даты в формате для сравнения
```

Однако дата каждый раз оказывалась на один день раньше обозначенной в ячейке. Т.е. если в ячейке 20.10.2019, то в результате работы метода formatDate получалось 19.10.2019.

Опытным путём я установил, что при считывании данных из ячейки её содержимое представляет собой строку "Sat Oct 19 01:00:00 GMT+03:00 2019" и если в части "01:00:00" первая цифра "0" (т.е. варианты "00", "01", "02" и т.д.) - то после использования функции formatDate дата на выходе получается на один день раньше, чем та, которая записана в ячейке в действительности.

На данный момент я проблему решил двумя дополнительными операциями:

```
  var lastDate = sheet.getRange(i-1,4).getValue();//Получение даты последней записи
  var lastDate = lastDate.toString().replace(/ 0.:/, " 10:");//Добавление "10" в первый разряд указателя времени "10:00:00" вместо "00:00:00" для правильной работы оператора преобразования формата даты, при этом тип переменной меняется 
  var lastDate = new Date(lastDate);//Преобразование строковой (после замены символов) переменной обратно в тип "Дата"
  var lastDate = Utilities.formatDate(lastDate, '+0300', 'dd.MM.yyyy');//Получение даты в формате для сравнения
```

Теперь всё работает правильно, но вряд-ли оно так действительно должно работать. Что я делал неправильно в первом варианте кода, что получал дату на день меньше той, которая приходил из ячейки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сравниваю даты как в js

```
/**
 * @param {Date} date
 */
function toTime(date, withoutTime) {
  var date_ = new Date(date);
  if (withoutTime === true) date_.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  return date_.getTime();
}

/**
 * comapre
 */
function compareDates() {
  var sheetDate = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValue();
  var currentDate = new Date();
  Logger.log(toTime(sheetDate) > toTime(currentDate));
  Logger.log(toTime(sheetDate, true) === toTime(currentDate, true));
}
```

`FormatDate()`, скорее всего, не для этого.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую так. Хотя и интересно, почему в принципе такая ситуация с FormatDate получается

Comment: Если вам интересно "в принципе", то попробуйте переформулировать вопрос. А проверьте настройки часовых поясов. У Таблицы и у скрипта они должны совпадать.

Comment: Проверил. Совпадают настройки часовых поясов. И там, и там: +02:00. Ладно не буду дальше себе голову ломать, решение найдено, большое Вам спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ уважаемого contributorpw натолкнул на ещё одну идею:

```
  var todayDate = new Date;//Получение текущей даты в системном формате
  var todayDateStr = todayDate.toDateString();//Преобразование в строковой формат следующего вида: "Wed Jul 28 1993"

  var lastDate = sheet.getRange(i-1,4).getValue();//Получение даты последней записи в системном формате
  var lastDateStr = lastDate.toDateString();//Преобразование в строковой формат следующего вида: "Wed Jul 28 1993"

 //Сравнение даты последней записи с текущей датой
 if (lastDateStr===todayDateStr) {

 }
```

Проверено - всё работает.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно не совсем корректно указывали параметр часовых поясов в изначальном коде, возможно Вам подойдет:

```
//Получение даты последней записи
var lastDate = sheet.getRange(i-1,4).getValue().toString();
//Получение даты в формате для сравнения
var lastDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(lastDate), "GMT+3", "dd.MM.yyyy").toString();
//Получение текущей даты
var todayDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+3", "dd.MM.yyyy").toString();
if(lastDate == todayDate ) {}
```